# forward_display_line doesn't work

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm using `Gtk.TextView` to display text, like this:

[image: TextView with wrapping]

My goal is to programmatically move the cursor to the start of the next **display** line (not the start of a buffer line, but instead the first character in the next `TextView` line).

It is using `Gtk.WrapMode.WORD_CHAR` as a wrapping preference. Moving `TextIter` objects works fine when accessed from the `TextBuffer`:

```
/* This works as expected */
Gtk.TextIter start_iter;
buffer.get_start_iter (out start_iter);
```

Or when working directly with the `TextIter`:

```
/* This also works as expected */
Gtk.TextIter iter;
...
iter.forward_line ();
```

But when I want to move the `TextIter` using `TextView`, e.g.:

```
Gtk.TextView text_view;
Gtk.TextIter iter;
...
text_view.forward_display_line (iter);
```

It doesn't move the iterator, despite `forward_display_line` returning `true` (signaling that the iterator has moved).

This is the code I'm using (inside of a class derived from `TextView`):

```
Gtk.TextIter line_end;
/* Initializing TextIter, placing it at the start of the buffer. */
this.buffer.get_start_iter (out line_end);

print ("Offset before forwarding: %i\n", line_end.get_offset ()); //returns 0

this.forward_display_line (line_end);

print ("Offset after forwarding: %i\n", line_end.get_offset ()); // still returns 0
```

Why doesn't this code work? Are `TextIter`s initialized by `TextBuffer` not appropriate for `TextView` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @José suggested, this is indeed a bug with Vala C bindings. The issue is posted [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/78).

I will try to fix this bug, and will update this answer if I succeed in fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you invoke the `Gtk.TextBuffer` [`forward_display_line()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TextView.forward_display_line.html) method which "consumes" a Gtk.TextIter but does not output this same "Iter" with the changes performed by the method. Both calls to `Gtk.TextIter` [`get_offset ()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TextIter.get_offset.html) should return the same value.

Instead, if you use the `Gtk.TextIter` [**`forward_line ()`**](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TextIter.forward_line.html), then the changes should and would be reflected in the second print, e.g.:

```
Gtk.TextIter line_end;
/* Initializing TextIter, placing it at the start of the buffer. */
this.buffer.get_start_iter (out line_end);

print ("Offset before forwarding: %i\n", line_end.get_offset ()); //returns 0

line_end.forward_line ();

print ("Offset after forwarding: %i\n", line_end.get_offset ()); // should be different from 0 if buffer has some text
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about me wanting to access the end of the **display** line (`forward_line` moves the `TextIter` to the end of the *buffer* line). I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović probably a bug.

Comment: I've filed a bug, for anyone interested:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/78